# concat против "+" ради оптимизации

Tags: java, строки, оптимизация

Во многих местах пишется что concat работает быстрее чем "+" для склеивания строк.
Но он например автоматически не преобразует иные типы, и для того чтобы склеить 2 числа переведенных в строку, нужно писать

```
String s = String.valueOf(num1).concat(String.valueOf(num2);
```

Когда можно просто написать

```
String s = num1 + "" + num2;
```

Есть ли ощущение оптимизации ? При условии что код становиться куда длиннее. 
Есть ли смысл заменять "+" на concat ?

Comment: А при чем тут ощущения? Нужно проводить замеры скорости работы. Желательно на тех машинах, на которых код будет выполняться. А вот какое ощущение действительно есть - что это попытка экономии на спичках или, что называется, "преждевременная оптимизация".

Comment: Вообще-то, для такой задачи есть `String.format` или `StringBuilder`... И выглядит красивее, и работает максимально быстро. Нельзя использовать "+" со строками, это можно рассматривать как табу. И, как упомянули выше, не стоит пытаться оптимизировать. Сначала напишите красиво, а уже потом, если возникнут проблемы - оптимизируйте.

Comment: Тут идея не в преждевременной оптимизации, а в том, как изначально делать правильнее.

Comment: `StringBuffer` или `StringBuilder` работают быстрее и экономнее расходуют память, `+` выглядит лаконичнее и понятнее. Использовать то или это зависит от вашего вкуса и конечных целей.

Comment: Кажется, ответ [на этот вопрос уже есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628/3832970).

Comment: как уже все написали, для ваших целей есть StringBuilder. Используйте его

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, с какой целью Вы делаете конкатенацию. Если конкатенация стала узким местом приложения - наиболее вероятно что что-то не так с самим приложением. Лучшее решение - вообще вынести эту операцию из критичного по производительности участка кода.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насчёт конкатенации, но при простом "сложении" обе части строки переводятся в символьные массивы, после чего неявно вызывается `StringBuilder` и далее уже наращивается `String` заново.

А так да, знак "+" предназначен больше для математических операций, со строками лучше использовать `String.format`.

`concat()` ни разу в жизни не пользовался.